# I want to charge my phone with AAs. How do I get that 5V output with max amperage (Would love to draw that 2.1A)

Tags: batteries, charging, battery-operated, telephone

I was just wondering around, looking for how to charge my phone on the go. Because Wednesday morning I'll go camping. I just don't want to buy a cheap chinese power bank to charge my phone once.

And then I found out that I can charge it with batteries, AAs probably being the best because they don't take up so much space and hold around 1500mAh and can output around 2A max. I am just asking, how should I do it?

- Should I wire two batteries (3V) in series and then make a step-up circuit (and how exactly would I make one with minimum power loss)?
- Or should I connect four (6V) and put some kind of regulator/resistors to it?
- Or could I just go with three batteries (4,5V) when my phone requires 5V
  (does it really require 5V, and could I still charge it relatively fast and at least efficient)?

As I already mentioned, I would like an output of 5V and over 750mA, and I'd like something closer to 2.1A. 
So what would be the most efficient and fast charge method (Efficieny first, I want the max juice out my AAs) that I could get my hands on before going, get all the parts (no ordering online) and building it all tomorrow?

Comment: Honestly, just buy a power bank.  After your trip you can try to build your own if you want to learn.

Comment: But I'm going for a week and I wanna charge my phone likes 3 or so times and a power bank that could do it is not really cheap/ available right now to me.

Comment: You are not going to build something like this out of junk until tomorrow. Forget it. Go to walmart, buy one, and return it to the store after the trip, if you can't afford it..

Comment: There is no way you are going to be able to design and build the necessary circuit tomorrow. Explore other options. You can buy an off-the-shelf solution from Amazon, but you would need to get overnight shipping. If you know how many mAh your cell phone battery is, that would help suggest a product that will work.

Comment: Anyway, I'll give you an idea. Do you have a car charger for the phone?  I would try to power it from 10 AAs.

Comment: There are power banks that use AAs.

Comment: I just checked on Amazon. There is an "amazonBasics" power pack family of products with different capacities. The largest one is 10,000 mAh and costs 30 bucks. There is also a 5,600 mAh one for 20 bucks. If you are in the US, this might be your best way to go (assuming you get overnight shipping). Walmart or costco or best buy would be another option.

Comment: Well, I live in Finland so I can not really get any of those things from amazon. No I dont have a car charger and 10 AAs is a lot, I hope it could the  charge my phone with all the powah the AAs hold. I might get a car charger to test that out... Maybe I should just go to one of my local big stores and see what I can get for 40€. My phone battery is 2100mah and I'd like to be able to charge it at least a few times.

Comment: And I also wonder how much does an amazon branded powerpack of 10000mah really have?

Comment: I don't have a good sense of what is available in Finland. Sorry about that. As far as your question about the Amazon brand product, is a decent brand and the item has a large number of mostly positive reviews. The number 1 positive review is written by famous reviewer NLee the Engineer. It is quite thorough. NLee calculated that the capacity seems to be slightly higher than advertised (you have to estimate capacity because the output voltage is actually 5V... the actual battery terminals are not available for charge/discharge). amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Portable-Power-Bank-000/dp/B00LRK8JDC

Comment: IpHONE ABOUT 1.5 Ah X 3 = 4.5 Ah. So 6000 mAh on up power bank OKISH.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a standard (quite good) [AA battery](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/E91.pdf). Let's have a look on its characteristics-curves and diagrams.

---

[image]

As you can see these AA batteries won't last for an hour if you want to draw 2.1A. Actually it won't last for an hour with 1A drawn, and it does not even work on its maximum voltage.

---

[image]

The other thing is: the higher the discharge current the lower the battery-capacity. At 500mA it is about 1500mAh, which is quite good. But with your desired minimum 750mA current it would be around 1000mAh or something like that. Moreover the voltage is only 0.8V here, almost half of the maximum.

---

All in all you would have to use a lot of AA batteries to charge your phone three times or even once. So as the others have already pointed out, it would be an easier solution to get a power-bank off the shelf.

Comment: Yea, thanks for that. I think I'll spend tomorrow going through all the stores near me searching for a big and rather cheap power bank. Thanks for that explanation, it really was good and I think I understood my problem :P

Comment: Though, when you will have more time you could do some experiments.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly valid reasons for wanting to charge your devices from AA batteries, but for the reasons Bence Kaulics pointed out it is not as simple as wiring AA batteries in parallel and connecting it to a USB port.  There are hobbyist projects like [MintyBoost](http://www.adafruit.com/product/14) that let you build the proper circuit to do this.  Physics still applies, and it will take multiple sets of AA batteries to get a full charge on a standard smartphone.