# Portable 1A battery phone charger

Tags: batteries, usb, battery-charging

I want to make a little battery-powered portable phone charger with 2x AAs that outputs 1A.

I have seen similar USB powered battery chargers such as the [Mintyboost](https://learn.adafruit.com/minty-boost) but it only outputs 500mA.

For 1A output, would the design be fairly similar? Does anyone know what changes would be needed to make Mintyboost give 1A? Instead of USB I'd use a micro-USB - would that be safe?

Thanks

Comment: The mintyboost only outputs 500mA because that's the upper limit on what a standard (non-charge) USB port can output; to do more you'll need to be able to negotiate with the charging device.

Comment: What do you mean by 'negotiating'? The charger I'm currently using outputs 1A - at least that's what it claims.

Comment: @Kar: it means that per usb protocol before being able to draw 1A you must ask the other end if it can provide that much. Remember that chargers dont push the 1A, the device draws it. If the device doesnt know that it can, it wont do it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Oh yeah, sure. AFAIK the Mintyboost doesn't seem to support such exchange - is there a way to support it?

Comment: Lets do some back of the envelope calculations. The Duracell coppertop AA datasheet suggests that at 1A draw the voltage plummets down quickly and within around an hour is at 1V. Assuming 85% efficiency for conversion to 5V/1A we need to draw 5.88W what the AA batteries, which is 1.9A when at 1.5V and 2.9A when at 1.0V per cell. With up to 300mΩ in the 1V state, this is barely what this duracell can deliver. And people will want to use cheap other cells.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this; it seems like a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: In addition to @PlasmaHH's comment: [about AA battery](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176791/i-want-to-charge-my-phone-with-aas-how-do-i-get-that-5v-output-with-max-amperag/176801#176801).

Comment: Re: PlasmaHH's "If the device doesnt know that it can, it wont do it." - This is just not true. Most of today's smartphones &c. draw just as much current as they need, or as much as the port actually will supply, whichever limit is reached first. Seeing 1A being drawn from a dumb-as-can-be USB "charger" w/o any data exchange is quite common.

Comment: "What do you mean by 'negotiating'?" - Have a look at the "USB Charging Specification". Basically, shorting the two USB data lines via a resistor (<=200Ohm, IIRC) is enough to let a compatible device know that it may draw more than normal USB current w/o any other negotiation.

Comment: @PlasmaHH the modern rechargeables "ready to use" (Enelopp and similar) can deliver over 90% of the stored charge up to 4A loads. http://www.eneloop.eu/fileadmin/web_data/Data-Sheets/HR-3UTGB.pdf

Comment: @OlafM: this is one remark I can see in sales being made that leads to products with "use only the following type of uncommon batteries:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB charging over 500mA works through negotiating with the host to determine if it's a standard downstream port (which supports up to 500mA power and comms), a charging downstream port (which supports up to 1.5A power and comms), or a dedicated charging port (which supports up to 1.5A but no USB communication). There's no way to tell a device it may only draw 1A, unfortunately - your limits are 500mA or 1.5A.

You can do this negotiation yourself with discrete circuitry or a microcontroller, but there are dedicated ICs to do this for you, such as the [TPS2540](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2540.pdf).

You'll also need to boost your battery voltage to 5V at the required 1.5A. I'm aware of the fantastic [PAM2401](http://diodes.com/datasheets/PAM2401.pdf), which is capable of boosting from 2xAA batteries with 5V output at 1 amp, with very few external parts. However, I'm not aware of any ICs that will support 1.5A output current with such low input voltages, unfortunately - and as PlasmaHH points out in the comments on your question, supplying enough current from two AA batteries may be problematic in the first place.

As far as connectors go, yes you could use a USB-OTG micro port - but OTG cables are a lot harder to find than regular ones, so unless you have a compelling reason to do so, it's probably simpler to stick with USB A.